# Python RabbitMQ sender.py remote queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to send a message to a rabbit mq queue in a remote machine. I am following [this](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html) tutorial.

The program to connect to localhost works fine. But the program to connect to remote queue doesn't work. The error must lie when creating the connection, because I can't see the log message 'connection created'.

I have verified I can access remotehost, port from my machine and the credentials are correct. I can access

```
http://remote-host:15672/#/queues
```

Am I missing any thing obvious?

**Local**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body='Hello World!')
print " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'"
connection.close()
```

**Remote**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

# this queue is the destination queue
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('xxxx', 'xxxx')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('remote-host', 15672, '/', credentials)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
print " connection created"

channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='helloEx', routing_key='', body='Hello World!')
print " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'"
connection.close()
```

**Update**
This is the error I am getting while trying to connect.

`ERROR:pika.adapters.base_connection:Socket Error on fd 3: 54 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "remote-sender.py", line 10, in     connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 61, in init
    super(BaseConnection, self).init(parameters, on_open_callback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/connection.py", line 513, in init    self._connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/connection.py", line 804, in _connect     self._adapter_connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 146, in _adapter_connect
    self.process_data_events()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 88, in process_data_events
    if self._handle_read():
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 184, in _handle_read
    super(BlockingConnection, self)._handle_read()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 300, in _handle_read
    return self._handle_error(error)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 264, in _handle_error
    self._handle_disconnect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 181, in _handle_disconnect
    self._on_connection_closed(None, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 235, in _on_connection_closed
    raise exceptions.AMQPConnectionError(*self.closing)
pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError: (0, '')`

Comment: Are you connecting with the guest account? The guest account can only connect via localhost. https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Comment: @kponz No. Not with the guest account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The virtual host needs to be specified correctly. In my case my queues belonged to a virtual host. But I was trying to connect to '/'. After specifying the virtual host (**product** below) I was able to connect successfully.

Found this [link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) is helpful.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

# this queue is the destination queue
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('xxxx', 'xxxx')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('remote-host', 5672, 'product', credentials)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
print " connection created"

channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='helloEx', routing_key='', body='Hello World!')
print " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'"
connection.close()
```

Comment: I am trying to use RabbitMQ on my localhost, but having hard time with it, can you give me any pointers regarding that

Comment: what is your specific problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use 5672 port and not 15672 !
It should work !

Comment: I did that. But I got the same results. I verified that I can access that port. Updated the question with the errors I got. Any idea what may be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @ravindrab, sorry I modified the port the correct is 5672!

Comment: I tried with the correct port 5672. Updated the answer with the errors I see.

Comment: Well, if it is not a firewall problem, you should check the rabbitmq logs to see if the connection arrives to RabbitMQ. I would suggest to read this post : https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/266

Comment: the problem was I haven't specify the vhost. `parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('remote-host', 5672, 'product', credentials)` did the trick.